# How to use "for" statement in Django template

Tags: django, templates

Here is Django template code.

I tried to put out images to template.

amount of image put out to template is depending on {{object.image_amount}}

However since {{object.image_amount}} is an integer I can not iterate like this

```
{% for i in object.image_amount %}
```

So I tried this but does not work as well.

```
{% for i in range object.image_amount %}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Django has no builtin `range`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you already have images that you need to show in your template
something like `object.images` or `object.images.all` if its related model
you can do
`{% for image in object.images.all %}`

Comment: I got it! Thank you.